# Ordering electrical supply

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm opening a kiosk in a mall. I need 100 amps (I will have a few fridges, grills, register, lightboxes).

Does that require a 220 line?

What does it depend on? Structure of the electricity in the mall?

I'm telling the electrician that I need 100 amps and he keeps asking me "what that is". Is that not enough information in order to update or get me a main connection?

Comment: What do the plugs on the equipment look like?  What country are you in?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about setting up a commercial retail business, not about improving a home or doing it yourself.

Comment: By the way if this is indoors you might have trouble using grills at a kiosk... generally any commercial cooking equipment requires an exhaust hood and sprinkler system.

Comment: Im in the US. The plugs are just regular ones.

Answer (score 2):

Just stating the amperage required is not enough information for the electrician to supply what you need.

If you are asking the electrician just to run a 100 amp metered main panel with no additional circuits or outlets for appliances, the amperage, voltage (e.g. 120V vs. 240V vs. 480V, etc.), and phase (1-phase vs. 3-phase) of the electricity should be enough information for the electrician to run the wiring for the panel.

If you are asking the electrician to run individual circuits to your appliances, then the electrician will need more detailed information about each appliance which can typically be found on the face-plate or a label on the equipment.

If you give the electrician some more information about each major appliance (or at least the type of appliances you will need if you have not picked them out yet) and the type of work spaces in your kiosk (e.g. kitchen), that should be enough to help get the conversation going further. If that doesn't get the conversation going any further, then you may want to look for another electrician who is willing to work with you on the specific details of your needs.

Comment: From the main panel I will need additional outlets for all of the appliances. So you say 100 amp would not be enough? I have a hard time explaining everything since English is not my first language, neither electricity.

Comment: @Maya I apologize, my first statement was ambiguous. I have clarified in my answer. 100 A could be enough, but I do not have enough information about the potential loads to comment.